# Javascript login using cURL in bash script

Tags: javascript, bash, http, curl, libcurl

I am trying to write a bash script in which I need to login to a website which uses javascript in its form. I have never used cURL so any help would be appreciated. I know I need to use cookies and I have the http headers, but I don't know what I need to do with these.

The headers are

```
Response Headers

Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Content-Length  0
Content-Type    text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date    Thu, 17 May 2012 11:25:15 GMT
Expires Tue, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified   Thu, 17 May 2012 11:25:16 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By    Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.3.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_3_GA  date=200807181417)/JBossWeb-2.0

Request Headers    
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie  SMLOGOUT=true; JSESSIONID=8D5757001A594D5CBB07C9250D1CB2B7; JSESSIONIDSSO=A0569CD1D6C981989F0FE691E9AFC314
Host    https:/example.com
Referer https://example.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0
X-WCF-Fragment  true
```

Any help or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you only these headers are sent? Wht are the data?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean?

Comment: In a HTTP response there are other parts. specially body, request method, type etc.

Comment: Edited to include all headers

Answer (score 3):

From the request header it can be easily seen that you are sending some post data. But you didn't provide it. I give you a simple example on how a http request can be converted to curl command.

Suppose you have this request  where you are posting 2 form variables `var1` and `var2` get POSTed to `http://www.example.com/form.url`. The request would look like this,

```
POST /form.url HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

var1=val1&var2=val2
```

When its converted to curl its like,

```
curl -d 'var1=val1&var2=val2' \
--header 'Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' \
--header 'Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' \
'http://www.example.com/form.url'
```

Note:

1. This way you can add as much as header you want. But its better you add only the headers which is necessary. Because `curl` will pass most headers for you (e.g. `Host`, `User-Agent`, `Content-Type`, `Accept` etc).
2. If you want to manage cookie add a file `cookie.txt` in the current directory and  `-b cookie.txt -c cookie.txt` command switches to curl. Means,

   ```
   -b/--cookie <name=string/file> Cookie string or file to read cookies from (H)
   -c/--cookie-jar <file> Write cookies to this file after operation (H)
   ```
3. `-d` switch stands for the data string that will be passed in the request body.

   ```
   -d/--data <data>   HTTP POST data (H)
   ```

Now I hope you can build your command.

Answer (score 2):

In http, there are two ways of sending data to a URL:

- POST
- GET

In *GET*, the data is sent as part of the URL. You may see a URL that looks like this:

```
http://foo.com/bar/barfoo/script.js?param1=this&param2=that&param3=the_other
```

This URL is sending data to a JavaScript at `http://foo.com/bar/barfoo/script.js`. It is sending to this script the following parameters:

- `param1` = *`this`*
- `param2` = *`that`*
- `param3` = *`the_other`*

In a *POST* operation, the data is sent differently and is not encoded in the URL itself. THis happens a lot when using web forms (like what you are trying to do). You can use the `--form` parameter in `curl` to pass POST data much like you word in a HTTP form.

From the CURL manage:

```
-F/--form <name=content>
    (HTTP) This lets curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has
    pressed the submit  button.  This  causes  curl  to  POST  data using
    the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This
    enables uploading of binary files etc. To force the 'content' part to
    be  a  file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the
    content part from a file, prefix the file name with the symbol <. The
    difference between @ and <  is  then  that  @  makes  a  file  get
    attached  in  the  post as a file upload, while the < makes a text
    field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.


Example, to send your password file to the server, where 'password' is the
name of  the  form- field to which /etc/passwd will be the input:

    curl -F password=@/etc/passwd www.mypasswords.com

To  read content from stdin instead of a file, use - as the filename. This
goes for both @ and < constructs.

You can also tell curl what Content-Type to use by using 'type=', in a
manner similar to:

    curl -F "web=@index.html;type=text/html" url.com

  or

    curl -F "name=daniel;type=text/foo" url.com

You can also explicitly change the name field of a file upload part by
setting filename=, like this:

    curl -F "file=@localfile;filename=nameinpost" url.com
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but curl doesn't do javascript.

consider

- manually deciphering the javascript and replicating the behavior in a perl/ruby/python script
- employing [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)