# How to use linux curl to login and retrieve data once logged?

Tags: angularjs, shell, post, curl, firebug

I have a device Stiebel Eltron heat pump home and I would like to use `Linux shell curl` (not php) curl to login (POST) and retrieve (GET) data once logged

Here is how my curl login POST call looks like (I used Firebug + *persist* option to copy/paste the below):

```
curl --data-urlencode 'userName=tutu&password=xx' \
'https://thesite/api/login?noCacheDummyValue=1459356436185' -X POST \
 -H 'Host: thesite' \
 -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0' \
 -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
 -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,fr-FR;q=0.3' \
 -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
 -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
 -H 'Referer: https://thesite/mobile/app/app.html' \
 -H 'Content-Length: 44' \
 -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=qhs02mfeip2p1n5n4t2rj1huu'
```

But this gives me nothing in the output:

```
 sh myproj.sh 
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

### Q1: What should I collect from this first `POST`, and how to do it?

I tried to get the cookie with `--cookie-jar cookie.txt` but nothing showed up in my current directory. However I sent cookies with the header... shouldn't I get them back?

After that I would like to continue the session I (think I) opened so to collect data from a GET that is (same method as above):

```
curl 'https://thesite/api/data/1036493/heatEnergy/today?noCacheDummyValue=1459356438440' \
     -H 'Host: thesite' \
     -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0' \
     -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
     -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.7,fr-FR;q=0.3' \
     -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
     -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
     -H 'Referer: https://thesite/mobile/dashboard/dash.html' \
     -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=qhs02mfeip2p1n5n4t2rj1huu'
```

### Q2: How do I keep the session opened to perform the `GET`above?

I  tried `--next` option [idea from here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) to call the `GET` after the `POST`; without success, `--next` option is not recognized on my Ubuntu Linux.

If it can help understanding, the page I should get is full of javascript (`angularjs` I think).

Comment: I did a similar thing back in the day where I wrote a script that connects to my Scottrade account and display my profit or loss in my tmux status bar.
There was a lot of trial and error and inspection of the requests with Chrome dev tools and right click copy as Curl. (What you are doing already). I think the reply you expect after the POST is just a cookie that you can pass along with the following GET request. I also had to use -L for follow redirect. Sorry can't help much without a working request.

Comment: I tried with `-L`, it is accepted by `curl`, but I only get another `curl: (52) Empty reply from server` .

Comment: Re Q1, for more diagnostic output add  **--trace-ascii debugdump.txt** to the **curl** command.

Comment: I tried with `--trace-ascii`, but didn't get any clue. I saw on http://stackoverflow.com/a/10634492/6019417 (c'mon, don't dup me guys) that `curl` doesn't do `javascript`:(. Is there a way for me to know if cookies are set with header or javascript? I see cookies in header, however...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `POST` call it is obvious that you are trying to do an ajax XMLHttpRequest. Likely this is expecting json encoded data. However you are providing url-encoded data.

Probably you should try using something along

```
... -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"userName":"tutu","password":"xx"}' 'https://thesite/api/login?noCacheDummyValue=1459356436185'
```

To make the *login* work, you need to match the way the server is maintaining the session. If session info is referred to via a cookie yo may just extract the cookie from the `POST` call (as you said you tried already, but on an error related response)

If the server does not use a straight way of referencing the session you might not succeed in getting your `GET` call working. If you are lucky maybe you then just need to parse a string from the page (fragment) or json data returned.

So monitor what a working handshake (e.g using a browser) is exchanging over the wire. And try identifing the important pieces of data. Then, put those together to form your GET call.

Comment: This is what I could not figure out alone. Thanks. I will write a full answer in case someone has same device and want to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rpy, I was able to do what I wanted:

### Collect the session cookie:

```
curl -a -X POST -d '{"userName":"tutu","password":"xx"}'                  \
 --trace-ascii debugdump.txt --cookie-jar cookies.txt                     \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8'                         \
-H 'Referer: https://thesite/mobile/app/app.html'                         \
   'https://thesite/api/login?noCacheDummyValue=1459356436185' -o my.post
```

- todo: check result is `"ok"` in `my.post`
- todo: get content of `cookies.txt` into `${COOKIE}`

### Use it to retrieve the raw data I wanted:

```
curl -a \
-H 'Referer: https://thesite/mobile/dashboard/dash.html'   \
-H 'Cookie:JSESSIONID='${COOKIE}                           \
   'https://thesite/api/data/1036493/outTemp/lastMonth?noCacheDummyValue=1459972646687'   \
   -o lm_outTemp.get \
-L 'https://thesite/api/data/1036493/heatEnergy/lastMonth?noCacheDummyValue=1459972646694' \
   -o lm_heatEnergy.get
```

And I already started working on how to process the data here: [Firefox - Collecting the data used by LAB.min.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36177365/firefox-collecting-the-data-used-by-lab-min-js)